# Any there unique features of data tables that I cannot reproduce using formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I did some calculations with a "data table" in Excel, but to me it looks like the same calculations could be done just copying the formula across rows and columns with a mix of absolute (using `$`) and relative references.

Are there any unique features of data tables, that can not be reproduced by other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: **No**, you can reproduce exactly the same results using formulas.

They are there for your convenience, to save you the time of having to set-up everything yourself.

> You can use data tables to see how different input values affect the results of a formula. By doing so, you can test different input values for a formula **without having to retype or copy the formula for each value**.
>
> -**[An overview of data tables in Excel 2003 and in Excel 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282852)**

Comment: Ok, looks to me to be indeed very useful when there are not only different input values, but where the formula is changed as well